# I don't understand why can't I get a combobox value

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, combobox

everyone.

This program is pretty simple, I have a combo box with two options, and by selecting either option, a new window appears, next it should have an updated list that is dependant on the previous selection. Then if the user selects any of the updated values, I have another function that takes that value, and should reflect it on the initial window.

I can't get past the if conditions, and python is not throwing me any errors or warnings; however, if I select an invisible option from the new window, python throws me an error saying that combo_2 is not defined.

I don't get what am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk 

root = Tk()
root.title('Example')


root.geometry('415x415')

starting_list = ['Option A', 'Option B']

def updating_lists(event):
    list_A = ['A_1', 'A_2', 'A_3']
    list_B = ['B_1', 'B_2', 'B_3']
    final_list = ['']
    top_1 = Toplevel()
    top_1.title('This window should have an updated list')
    top_1.geometry('220x220')
    
    if combo_1.get() == 'Option A':
        print('you have selected option A')
        final_list = list_A
        
    elif combo_1.get() == 'Option B':
        print('you have selected option B')
        final_list = list_B
        
    combo_2 = ttk.Combobox(top_1, values = final_list, state = 'readonly')
    combo_2.pack()
    combo_2.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', update_values)
    
def update_values(event):    
    variable_1 = combo_2.get()
    print(f'variable combo_2.get() is: {combo_2.get()}')
    print(f'variable_1 is: {variable_1}')
    top_1.destroy()
    return(variable_1)
    
###########################################
#               Frame A                   #
###########################################

frame_A = LabelFrame(root, width = 400, height = 400, text = 'Example', padx = 5, pady = 5)
frame_A.grid_propagate(0)
frame_A.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 5)

variable_1 = StringVar(root, '')

combo_1 = ttk.Combobox(frame_A, values = starting_list, state = 'readonly', width = 15)
combo_1.set('Choose one')
combo_1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
combo_1.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', updating_lists)

label_1 = Label(frame_A, textvariable = variable_1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
label_1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

I'm working in windows 10, with python 3.

Comment: Have you checked what `combo_1.get()` is returning? I'm guessing you're assuming it's returning something that it is not. Add the following line inside the function: `print(combo_1.get())`. The first step in debugging is to try to verify that your assumptions are correct.

Comment: You are absolutely right! I got the ifs wrong. I just edited my code, and now I can pass the if conditions, got the updated lists corrected as well, but right now is giving me trouble in the second part (update_values) throwing me a combo_2 is not defined

Comment: `combo_2` is a local variable, so no other function can see it.

Comment: I'm guessing combo_1 was not a local variable? Thanks for the answer, I'm going to update the code in an answer.

Comment: correct, `combo_1` is a global variable because it's defined outside of a function.

Comment: I have advanced to the final part, but still stuck. I was trying to make variable_1 into a global,  but it is still not working (I'm getting a null value?)... correct me if I'm wrong does the `combo_2.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', function)` is going to stop the flow until the conditions are meet? or it just pass that line of code?

Comment: no, calling `bind` does not stop anything.

Answer (score 0):

As Bryan Oakley pointed out, I was having some mistakes in my code, first one was in the if condition (something really silly, so forget about it), second mistake, was me assuming that combo_2 was global, it is not, so what I did was to declare top_1 and combo_2 as globals. I was trying to declare another variable as global, but this was not working, because my third mistake was assuming that the .bind was stopping the flow, but it wasn't and it was filling this variable with nothing.

Adding the correct code... That I think is not the best, but it works.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title('Example')

root.geometry('415x415')

starting_list = ['Option A', 'Option B']

def updating_lists(event):
    list_A = ['A_1', 'A_2', 'A_3']
    list_B = ['B_1', 'B_2', 'B_3']
    final_list = ['']
    global top_1
    global combo_2
    top_1 = Toplevel()
    top_1.title('This window should have an updated list')
    top_1.geometry('220x220')
    
    if combo_1.get() == 'Option A':
        print('you selected option A')
        final_list = list_A
        
    elif combo_1.get() == 'Option B':
        print('you selected option B')
        final_list = list_B
        
    combo_2 = ttk.Combobox(top_1, values = final_list, state = 'readonly')
    combo_2.pack()
    combo_2.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', terminate_top)
    
def terminate_top(event):
    print(f'combo_2.get is: {combo_2.get()}')
    label_1 = Label(frame_A, text = str(combo_2.get()), padx = 5, pady = 5)
    label_1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    top_1.destroy()
    
###########################################
#               Frame A                   #
###########################################

frame_A = LabelFrame(root, width = 400, height = 400, text = 'Example', padx = 5, pady = 5)
frame_A.grid_propagate(0)
frame_A.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 5)

combo_1 = ttk.Combobox(frame_A, values = starting_list, state = 'readonly', width = 15)
combo_1.set('Choose one')
combo_1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
combo_1.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', updating_lists)

root.mainloop()
```

Thank you very much for the tips!